# imprimir texto con etiquetas reemplazables por datos traídos de base

Tags: php, mysql, html5, mysqli, php7

Obtengo de tablas de base de datos el nombre de un alumno, el nombre de un profesor y el nombre de un curso.  Y de otra tabla extraigo un texto en donde debo tener identificadores para que allí se reemplacen los datos de nombre del profesor y del alumno. Por ejemplo: El profesor {{nombreprofesor}} exoneró al alumno {{nombrealumno}} el examen final considerando el promedio acumulado en el curso {{nombrecurso}}. Al momento de imprimir debo presentar en un textarea el texto con los datos obtenidos de la base.

Comment: Buenas, Martín, bienvenido al sitio. ¿Cuál es la pregunta exactamente? Échale un ojo al [tour]

Comment: Necesito saber como puedo hacer eso utilizando php y mysql por favor

Comment: Es que esto no es un servicio gratuito de resolución de ejercicios. Te tienes que instalar PHP, MySQL, un servidor, crear las tablas y la página web que se te pide. Si te atrancas en algún problema concreto con las consultas o el código php, copias aquí lo que has hecho y qué error tienes y entonces se te intentará ayudar.

Comment: Te sugiero que hagas caso a RubioRic, pero como dices que "obtengo", entonces entiendo que ya has hecho el trabajo y lo único que necesitas es remplazar los tokens {{}} por los datos, si eso es lo que buscas, haz bien tu pregunta, añade el código que tienes y ya de paso te sugiero que busques información sobre str_replace de php

Comment: Hola. ¿Dices que los datos vienen así: `{{nombreprofesor}}`? Pues habría que preguntarse por qué vienen así y no en su forma natural: `nombreprofesor`. Otra cosa sería si están guardados como JSON , en cuyo caso lo mejor sería convertirlos a objeto o array. Sea como sea, no aportas ningún código y eso impide que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Hola chicos... disculpa por la forma como formulé la pregunta... soy nuevo y la verdad viendo no lo realicé de la mejor forma.  Lo que indicó track3r fue de mucha ayuda.  Lo realicé así: 
    $varCaracteres = array ("{{doctor}}", "{{paciente}}");
 $varCaracteresHTML = array ("Juan Perez", "Maria Charapova");
    $textoinicial = '
        CONSENTIMIENTO PARA EXTRACCIÓN DE DIENTE: Por la presente se autoriza al Dr. {doctor} la extracción del diente al paciente {paciente}. 
    $textofinal = preg_replace($varCaracteres, $varCaracteresHTML, $textoinicial);